# Ruby on rails number_to_phone helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have the following line in my application,

```
<%= f.telephone_field number_to_phone(1235551234) , placeHolder: 'Telephone', :class => 'form-control' %>
```

But when I browse the page, I'm consistently getting the following error.

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `123-555-1234' for #<User:0x007fcca00ef690>:
```

I have tried that one but it didn't work either.

```
<%= f.telephone_field ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper.number_to_phone(1235551234) , placeHolder: 'Telephone', :class => 'form-control' %>
```

I can't see what I'm missing ?

Any suggestions,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> NoMethodError - undefined method `123-555-1234' for
>   User:0x007fcca00ef690
>
> telephone_field(object_name, method, options = {}) public
>
> Returns a text_field of type “tel”.
>
> telephone_field("user", "phone")
>
> `#=><input id="user_phone" name="user[phone]" type="tel" />`

The problem is **not with** `number_to_phone` helper. All *form helpers* expect `method`(*attribute of a model*)as a *second argument*. You should pass an *attribute* of your `User` model to which you want to save the input. For example lets say your attribute name is `phone_number`, then write it like below

```
<%= f.telephone_field :phone_number , placeHolder: 'Telephone', :class => 'form-control' %>
```

And in the view where you are displaying the `phone_number`, use `number_to_phone` helper

```
<%= number_to_phone(@user.phone_number) %>
```

Comment: according to your suggestion, I have checked the code with <%= f.telephone_field number_to_phone(@user.tel), placeHolder: 'Telephone', :class => 'form-control' %>, but I'm getting the same mistake :(

Comment: @HilmiYamcı You didnt read my answer carefully. Read it again!

Comment: @HilmiYamcı What Pavan says is that you  **can't use the helper when creating the `input`**, so don't use the helper with `t.telephone_field` (as shown in the answer). You can use the helper only for displaying the actual value of `phone_number` field.